# Using the Groovy DSL, how do I let the user chose a node?

Tags: jenkins

I have a primary server running Jenkins, and it is attached to 5 nodes. I want the user (all members of our QA team) to be able to log in, deploy a particular git branch to a particular node, and then go and do QA on that particular node.

In the Jenkinsfile, I tried this:

```
stage('Which test server?') {

    try {
        timeout(time: 180, unit: 'SECONDS') { // change to a convenient timeout for you

          parameters {
            nodeParam('TEST_HOST') {
              description('select test host')
              defaultNodes(['node1'])
              allowedNodes(['node1', 'node2', 'node3'])
              trigger('multiSelectionDisallowed')
              eligibility('IgnoreOfflineNodeEligibility')
            }
         }
       }   
    } catch(e) { // timeout reached or input false

        println "An exception occurred during the 'Which test server' stage:"
        println e.getMessage()
        throw e

    }
    println "End of the 'Which test server' stage"        
}
```

But this did not give any kind of popup or dialogue. What do I need to do to let the users chose?